# How to View multiple images which retrieve with explode from a single row of table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this below code to retrieve image name and explode and  to display. but the problem is the output. in out put view one extra blank image is displaying at the end in this below 75 id it consist of only 2 image name but it displaying 2 image with one blank image. Any help to solve this problem will be appreciate.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<?php
$sql1=mysql_query("Select * from multiimg WHERE id=75");

$result=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
/*$images = explode(",",$result['image']);

if(sizeof($images) > 0 ){
  foreach($images as $image){
   echo '<img src="photo/'.$image.'" height="50" width="50">' ;
   echo "<br />"; 
  }
}*/

$temp = explode(',',$result['image'] );

foreach($temp as $image){
    $images[]="photo/".trim( str_replace( array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );

}

//now your array of images cotaines to full source to each image

foreach($images as $image){
  echo "<img src='{$image}' height='100' width='200' />";
}
?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Your $images array have three items in it. Trace your upto 'foreach($images as $image)' to know what happens.

Comment: It won't help untill you show us the table structure.

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions, they are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP releases.

Comment: Trim the comma at the end of your `image` inputs in your table. See my answer that will also help with other things you can do.

Comment: it displaying nothing @Rasclatt

Comment: Are you doing the `is_file`? If so you have to have a `root` defined (if set, you could use something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or if you have a `config` file in your `root`, you can define a `root` there). Try trimming the end comma first.

Comment: If you do noting else, trim the `$result['image']` of the last comma. That is what is generating your empty key/value pair

Comment: Sorry @Rasclatt i am a new bie to thi and ve no knowledge about the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: That's ok. No problem. Try just doing `$result['image'] = trim($result['image'],'\,');` (I don't think you have to escape the comma, but I do anyway)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67198/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-sameer-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things you can do to get around this. One is to **trim/remove the comma at the end of your image inputs in your table** and the others are:

**EDIT** Add a `trim()` first:

```
// (I don't think you have to escape the comma, but I do anyway)
$result['image'] = trim($result['image'],'\,');

// Explode array
$temp = explode(',',$result['image'] );

// use array_filter() to remove empty key/values
// I had this filtering $images, but probably best to
// filter the original exploded array $temp
$temp = array_filter($temp);

foreach($temp as $image){
    $images[]="photo/".trim( str_replace( array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
}    

foreach($images as $image){
  // Use an if here...you could use a root directory if defined previously.
  // Use whatever you like to check if the file exists
  if(is_file(ROOTDIR.$image))
      echo "<img src='{$image}' height='100' width='200' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but try adding a trim statement before explode
like

```
 $images = trim($result['image'], "'");
 $temp = explode(',', $images);
```

Answer (score 0):

First print and see how many images you are getting from the database. if they are correct as you need then do this or use trim to remove blank before this:

```
$temp = explode(',',$result['image'] );

foreach($temp as $image)
{
$images="photo/".$image;


 echo "<img src='$images' height='100' width='200' />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i sure whatever you want that you will getting from this below code. and one more thing if you get blank image than please check whether that images is exist in your folder from wherever you are trying to get..

```html
<?php
$sql1=mysql_query("Select * from multiimg WHERE id=75");
$result=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
$images=$result['image'];
$remove_last_comma=substr($images,0,-1);
$temp = explode(',',$remove_last_comma);
for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++)
{
 echo '<img src="photo/'.trim($temp[$i]).'" height="50" width="50">';
 echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";  
}
?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: still the blank image coming at the end @Mahendra Pumbhadiya

Comment: Mr Sameer Pls check now and try code earlier code little bit i have change i.e for($i=0;$i<=count($temp);$i++) to for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++)